# Extension of a binary operation

Tags: group-theory

Could you help me with the following problem?

Let $X$ be a set with a (not necessarily associative) binary operation. Let $o$ be an element such that $o \not \in X$ and let $X^o=X \cup \{o\}$.

Show that there exists only one extension of the operation on $X$ to an operation on $X^o$ such that $o$ is it's neutral element.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: If $x,y\in X$, the product $xy$ is predetermined. What $ox$, $xo$ and $oo$ should be?

Comment: Every entry of the multiplication table for $X\cup\{o\}$ is determined by the condition $o$ is a neutral element.

Comment: I'm very sorry. The operation needn't be associative, not commutative. I must have had something else on my mind. Sorry for misleading you. I'll correct it right away.

Comment: @Hagrid: Are you working on a monoid?

Comment: No, I'm not. At least that's how I understand what the problem says. The operation needn't be associative and since $o$ is identity in $X^o$ and $o \not \in X$ and there can be only one identity in a set, then this means that there is no identity in $X$. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @egreg We are dealing with extension of an operation, so the results of operations on the elements of $X$ are predetermined. And since $o$ is identity element, then #xo$ and $ox$ are also clearly determined. But it that enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An operation on $X$ is a function $X\times X\to X$, so when you've specified the action on all pairs, you have it.

Let's denote by $\cdot$ the original operation on $X$ and by $\bullet$ the operation on $X^o=X\cup\{o\}$.

Then, for $x$ and $y$ in $X$, we must have

$$x\bullet y=x\cdot y,$$

because we want an operation that extends the original one, while we want that $o$ is the neutral element in $X^o$, which forces

\begin{gather}
o\bullet x=x\\
x\bullet o=x\\
o\bullet o=o
\end{gather}

for all $x\in X$. There's no missing pair, because a pair of elements in $X^o\times X^o$ either has $o$ or not, so it must be of one of the forms

$$(x,y),\quad (o,x),\quad (x,o),\quad (o,o)$$

with $x,y\in X$.

Therefore the extension is unique as required.

Comment: The matter got fixed. Next time, if you intend to write an answer, please just do it. Leaving a comment like yours looks very much like [dog's pissing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spraying_(animal_behavior)#Other_animals), and it is not alright with respect to those that got the same idea as you.

Comment: @dtldarek I'll keep it in mind; but people has something to do in addition to answering here. I understand that the site is quite competitive, but half an hour doesn't seem too much to me.